# 'en' contre 'de là'

Tags: traduction

Bonjour à toutes et tous,

Quelle est la meillure traduction de la phrase "He falls from there." ?

Il en tombe.

Ou

Il tombe de là.

Et pourquoi ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il me semble qu'il n'y a pas de "meilleure" traduction dans l'absolu. Cela dépend du contexte.

Ceci étant dit, "de là" est plus précis que "en" (si c'est de "là", ce n'est pas d'"ici"). Donc si le lieu est important, j'utiliserais "de là".

```
J'ai tout vu! Il est tombé de là.
```

Par contre, "en" insiste sur l'objet d'où l'on tombe.

```
Il était monté sur une chaise et il en est tombé.
```

D'une manière générale, la langue française accorde moins d'importance à "ici" et "là-bas" qu'en anglais (ex: les déterminants this/that thing -> ce truc (plus rarement ce truc-ci, ce truc-là). Ce qui serait un (petit) argument pour le "en".

Comment: Radouxju parfait ! merci !